# View not updating after event triggered with controller attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ive developed a search bar that triggers an event when its done searching. A listener of the event is a controller that asigns the info passed from the search bar to an attribute that is binded to the view in the form of `{{ controller.node.name }}`

```
app.controller('Controller', function($rootScope){
  this.node = undefined;

  $rootScope.$on('searchEvent', function(event, info) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        set(info);
      });
    }, 0);
  });

  function set(c) {
    this.node = c;
  }
});
```

I read about `$scope.$apply` and used the solutions they provide, however the examples use `$scope.node` instead of `controller.attribute` as Im doing.

I've tried with `$scope.node` and it works, the questions is, why isn't it working with a controller attribute?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called.

When `set` is called `this` has a different value, so you are not really editing the same `node`, and instead you are creating a `node` variable on this new `this`

If you use a variable instead of `this`, you make sure you are referencing the same variable

```
app.controller('Controller', function($rootScope){
    var self = this;
    self.node = undefined;

    function set(c) {
        self.node = c;
    }
});
```

More info on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)